# Why does VBA editor opens Outlook?

Tags: vba, excel, vbe

Sometimes when I'm inspecting some variable on my excel macro, Outlook opens up by itself. This is pretty annoying since I don't even use Outlook nor have it configured. What is happening here?

I'm using Office 2016.

---

**Edit:** I don't think this has any to do with the actual macro, but anyway, here it goes:

```
Sub duplicateSheets()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 3
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("classes").Copy _
            After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("pivot").Copy _
            After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    Next
End Sub
```

Outlook opens when I'm inspecting `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("classes")`.

Comment: This isn't clear - what does your macro contain? Unless this is just a coincidence of some type, it would seem you have code in your macro attempting to access a property of Outlook, which opens it as a result.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon see my edit

Comment: That's very weird... so it happens consistently when you inspect the variable?

Comment: Yes, very weid... I even created another file to make sure it has nothing to do with the content of the sheets, and it happened again

Comment: For what it's worth, I've attempted to recreate your situation, and it doesn't do the same thing for me. This is with Office 2010.

Comment: Uninstall Outlook from your PC if you are not using it. You may also need to repair your current Office installation.

Comment: does the `Sheets("classes")` have any event code inside it (that possibly could be causing issue). I assume it doesn't because of your previous comment, but thought I would check anyway.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman my original file had the `Workbook_Open` that would call a different Sub, but as I said, I've tried with a minimal test case, with only the Copy method (no workbook events), and the situation happened again

Comment: @IronMan yes, I guess I'll have to do that, although it seems uninstalling only one tool of the Office 2016 package isn't as straight forward as one would expect

Comment: Try running a repair first. That may be easier than trying to uninstall Outlook alone.

Comment: search for the word "outlook" in your vba project !

Comment: I had Outlook startup on me unexpectedly yesterday. I had Excel and VBA editor open - I never tried to repeat the problem.

Comment: Something to do with Mail envelope? (Look at a variant in debug mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had something similar happen to me before only with Access. My Excel VBA code never interacted with Access but it would still open up. Never got any errors from it, but I agree, it is rather annoying to have to close it every time.

After searching around I found that it was because I had the `Microsoft Access 15.0 Object Library` reference turned on. I guess some property or method that I would call from my Excel VBA would somehow trigger something in the Access Library and it would open up the application.

See if you have any Library references to `Outlook` enabled and turn them off, it might fix the issue you are having.

Comment: Probably you are right, I didn't had the Outlook reference explicitly, but I see that I had the `Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library` is on. Maybe only the `Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library` is enough.

Comment: Just tested the code, and actually the problem does not happen anymore (my Windows 10 was updated a few times since I first posted this question). But I guess this is the way to go to whom may have this problem in the future. Thanks a lot.